# VBA Excel 2013 returning specific values of an array from a UD Function

Tags: arrays, function, excel, vba

My intent is to retrieve a specific value of an array (either static or dynamic) while being called from a function in a way such as the following

define my function and inside the function define my array. For instance

```
Function MonthNames()
  MonthNames = Array(“January”, “February”, “March”, _
   “April”, “May”, “June”, “July”, “August”, _
   “September”, “October”, “November”, “December”)
End Function
```

I would like to type then in cell

=monthnames(2) to have "March" in the cell.

Would that be possible somehow? I tried it but it doesn"t work. How could I retrieve specific values from that array by using multiple times the same function in various cells with these values from the array?

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Note: I don't want to use subroutines (if possible) as I lose the advantage of undo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array is zero based so you'll want to subrtact one from the index, and you need to declare that as a parameter:

```
Function MonthNames(lIndex As Long)
   MonthNames = Array("January", "February", "March", _
   "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", _
   "September", "October", "November", "December")(lIndex - 1)
End Function
```

Comment: Worked! Thank you very much!